# Narrowing a type to a constant for Typescript in a .js file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some `.js` config files and a tsconfig for these files with `checkJs: true`. A library (Terser) has the type:

`ecma: 5 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020`

In my config file, I have `ecma: 2017`. TS considers its type to be `ecma: number`. In a `.ts` file, I can just use `as const`. In a `.js` file, is there any way to get TS to narrow `2017` to a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a const assertion in jsdoc, as detailed in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30445)

```
// let config: {
//     readonly ecma: "2017";
// }
let config = /** @type {const} */ ({ 
  ecma: "2017"
})

// Or 
// let config2: {
//     ecma: "2017";
// }
let config2 = { 
  ecma: /** @type {const} */ ("2017")
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=js&useJavaScript=trueq=17#code/PTAEBsFMBdQYwPYDsBmBLA5gLlAbwLABQIoppATpAIYAmy4AnqJHALZU4BEATAAwCMAdk4BuIiQC+RKLESpMoALyhgAKlWgAAtAYAHSHjkBnaBNCqwAClygipFuy58hnIhICURcWADy5W8RgMvDI6BjcOASBZPZsHKA8AsJi0VKEwXJh3Ep4AbGOKupaOvqGyCZmFqCWiS6ehBJAA)

Note: the `()` around the expression you want to make const is required.

Answer (score 0):

I would do two things in a combination to ensure it is a constant:

First - make sure that the props is not changeable runtime nomatter what.

```
///config.js
const config = {
  anotherProp: true,
  ecma: 2017
};
Object.defineProperty(config, "ecma", { value: 2017, writable: false });
export default config;
```

Second create d.ts file to "tests" the typescirpt this prop is readonly

```
/// config.d.ts
type Config = {
  anotherProp: string;
  readonly ecma: 2017;
};

declare const conf: Config;

export default conf;
```

The result will be that the typescript will complain about changes

```
//ts error: Cannot assign to 'ecma' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)
config.ecma = 6;
```

And even If you try to hack it - it will fail runtime:

```js
//runtime error: Cannot assign to read only property 'ecma' of object '#<Object>'
(config as any).ecma = 6;
```

Playground link here: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-chaum-z8bfwq?file=/src/index.ts)